# Regex - Trying to adjust several lines of coding

Tags: regex

I'm working on developing a program and realized I have made a mistake on a few lines: This line here:

```
CInt(DBRead(userfile, "Stats", "MaxHP", String.Empty))
```

For example, should become

```
CInt(DBRead(userfile, "Stats", "MaxHP", "0"))
```

The idea here is that string.empty obviously can't be converted to Cint. The last variable is meant to be 'default if not found'.

```
CInt(DBRead(filename, section, name, default))
```

What I want to do now is find any lines that start with `CInt(DBRead(` and have `String.Empty))`, and then adjust the `String.Empty` to `0`. Is this possible, specially because these aren't typically the start or the end of the lines they are on.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the _lookbehind_ operator: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should parse your String.Empty s:

```
(?<=CInt.*?,.*?,\s?)String\.Empty(?=\))
```